# Accessing dynamic values from config files in a module file with Angular

Tags: angular

below is the part of my config-dev.json file

```
"authConfig": {     
  "stsServer": "https://xxx-dev.xxx.com/cls/security/authorization/v2",
  "redirectUrl": "https://xxx-dev.xxx.com/grids/security/authCallback",
  "clientId": "xxxxxx",      
},
```

I am setting authentication related configurations in my config files for all environments like config-dev.json, config-qa.json etc.

So, after the latest changes in the package which I am using (angular-auth-oidc-client), few things are changes in which I need to make necessary changes in my code too.

Below is part of my auth-config.module.ts file

```
export const authValues: OpenIdConfiguration | OpenIdConfiguration[] = {
  "stsServer": "https://xxx-dev.xxx.com/cls/security/authorization/v2",
  "redirectUrl": "https://xxx-dev.cscglobal.com/grids/security/authCallback",
  "clientId": "xxxxxx",      
}

@NgModule({
   imports: [AuthModule.forRoot({config: authValues})],    
   exports: [AuthModule],
})
```

Now, I need to provide config values under forRoot method. Here what I am unable to understand is how can I get the values from respective environment's config files dynamically? By giving them manually in a constant like in the above example I can only set for one environment.

For other scenarios in my application, I used to get the dynamic values by providing AppConfig file in constructor and then by accessing the values.

app.config.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class AppConfig {
public config: any;

constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

public load() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.httpClient.get('/conf/config.json')
        .subscribe((configData) => {
            this.config = configData;
            resolve(true);
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    });
}
}
```

After loading this in constructor in any component or service class, I can access config file's values by just doing

```
constructor(private appConfig: AppConfig)
```

then

```
this.appConfig.config.authConfig.stsServer
```

But by using above approach I am not able to get the values in the module file. Is there any alternative approach which I can follow to get these dynamic values. Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just set up [file replacements](https://angular.io/guide/build) and Angular will make sure you have the right file according to the environment you're running on.

Comment: We are already using fileReplacements in angular.json file to replace config files based on the environment like {
  "replace": "src/conf/config.json",
  "with": "src/conf/config.qa.json"
} but the problem is getting values from those config files

Comment: Once file replacements are set up you just have to use `import { environment } from 'environment-file-path'`